# ggplot separate legend for regression lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'd like to have two legends on a ggplot scatter plot: one for the point colors, and another for the regression line colors.

Can you explain how to add a separate legend for the two regression lines here?

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = gear)) + 
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula=y~x, se = FALSE, size = 0.5, color = 'dark green') + 
  geom_smooth(method='lm', aes(mpg, hp), data = mtcars[mtcars$wt > 3, ], se = FALSE, size = 0.5, color = 'dark orange', fullrange = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 5):

Two points to note:

1. By default, ggplot will produce **only** one legend for each mapped aesthetic, based on all geoms that specify `aes(color = XXX, ...)`. One workaround for creating separate legends is to utilise the fact that some shapes (which can be specified within `geom_point()`) can take on a `fill` aesthetic as well as a `color` aesthetic.

[image: screenshot]

Image taken from [here](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/shape). Shapes 21-25 accept both `color` (indicated in black) & `fill` (indicated in red).

2. In order to create a legend, the aesthetic must be specified **inside** `aes()`. But sometimes we wish to specify the color directly for each line. One workaround is to use the `scale_XXX_manual()` option, which allows you to specify `aes(color = "some label")` within the geom, and map the color in `scale_color_manual(values = c("some label" = "some color"))`

Code:

```
ggplot(mtcars,
       aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = gear), shape = 21) +          # specify shape here
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y~x, 
              se = FALSE, size = 0.5,
              aes(color = "lm1")) +                   # specify color within aes()
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = FALSE, size = 0.5,
              data = mtcars[mtcars$wt > 3, ],
              aes(x = mpg, y = hp, color = "lm2"),    # as above
              fullrange = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_continuous(name = "Points") +            # legend name
  scale_color_manual(name = "Regression",             # legend name
                     values = c("lm1" = "darkgreen",  # map regression line colors
                                "lm2" = "darkorange"))
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

the issue is because the gear is a numerical value, if you want a separate legend, you need using the discrete value, like **factor** or **character** data type, so you can change the layer of `geom_point` like that:

```
    geom_point(aes(color = factor(gear)))
```

Comment: This makes a factor, yes. However, I'm still not sure how to make a separate legend for my two regression lines.